# show $2^\sqrt{2}$ on the real numbers line

Tags: real-numbers

**How can I show $2^\sqrt{2}$ on the real numbers line?**

Comment: What do you mean by "show on the real line"?

Comment: something like that: http://s3.img7.ir/DVhgd.jpg

Comment: @AliPh Do you mean a geometric representation of $2^{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: not exactly but it's better than noting

Comment: please try to reword your question more carefully so that people are more willing to help you.

Comment: I think the OP may be trying to ask how to show the number $\;2^{\sqrt2}\;$ is constructible...

Answer (score 2):

According to the calculator, $2^{\sqrt{2}} \approx 2.665144142$.
It is a transcendental number.  There is no geometric construction of it.

So here it is on a number line.

[image]

Comment: you are wrong I'm sure

Comment: What do you think I'm wrong about?

Comment: @Robert first you said that it is transcedental and there is no geometric construction of it and then you represent it on number line. How??

Comment: by y=2^x you can show $2^\sqrt{2}$(when x=√2 , y= $2^\sqrt{2})      but i'm looking for a better way http://s3.img7.ir/y2IFE.png

Comment: Do you get it??

Comment: This number is called "Gelfond–Schneider constant" and as transcendental it is not constructable using straight edge and pair of compasses (and possibly some other construction equipment).

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Approximately.

Comment: @AliPh What would count as better?

Comment: I can't graph y=2^x by hand it's better a way that can graph by hand